# How could I speed up the loading of a ImageView in listView while using SimpleCursorAdapter?

Tags: android, listview, imageview, lazy-evaluation

Hey my question is how can I speed up the loading of my listView...because I have the problem that it is realy lazy because of the ImageView. But how could I load the pictures in my cache?
I'm using the simple cursor adapter to load the data from my Sql Database. Here is my code:

```
void populateListViewFromDB() {

    Cursor cursor = myDb.getAllRows();

    // Allow activity to manage lifetime of the cursor.
    // DEPRECATED! Runs on the UI thread, OK for small/short queries.
    getActivity().startManagingCursor(cursor);
    //if (cursor.moveToLast()) {
        //  do {
        // do what you need with the cursor here


    // Setup mapping from cursor to view fields:
    String[] fromFieldNames = new String[] 
            {DBAdapter.KEY_NAME,DBAdapter.KEY_PRICE,DBAdapter.KEY_LEVEL,DBAdapter.KEY_ART,DBAdapter.KEY_VALUETXT,DBAdapter.KEY_PIC };
    int[] toViewIDs = new int[]
            {R.id.tv_Shop_item1,     R.id.tv_Shop_Price_item1,R.id.tv_shop_Level_item1,R.id.tv_shop_use_item1,R.id.tv_shop_use_item2,R.id.IV_Shop_item1 };

    // Create adapter to may columns of the DB onto elemesnt in the UI.
    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter = 
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    getActivity().getApplicationContext(),      // Context
                    R.layout.item_shop, // Row layout template
                    cursor,                 // cursor (set of DB records to map)
                    fromFieldNames,         // DB Column names
                    toViewIDs               // View IDs to put information in
                    );

    // Set the adapter for the list view

    myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
     //  } while (cursor.moveToPrevious());
    //}
}
```

Or is there any other way to add the pictures to the ListView? Because I always read other Questions how to safe bitmaps in the Chache...

Thanks for helping and sorry for my bad englsih..Im from Germany;)

Comment: Have you read this? basically load the images in a background thread and cache them and then use them when you need them. http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html#disk-cache

Comment: Would this work with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this library. It's very solid and well featured image loading library with cache support.

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: but this pictures are in my drawable folder is that a problem

Comment: and how could I add the picture to my ListView?

Comment: You can also load images on drawable folder with the library.